# Why is the "Create Pull Request" menu item in Visual Studio 2015 always disabled?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

No matter what I try, this menu item never seems to "enable":

[image]

What am I missing?  This is in VS 2015 Update1 pointed at a Git repo on TFS 2015.

Comment: Can you create a pull request from the web portal? It's under CODE > Pull Requests > Create new Pull Request

Comment: Yes that works just fine.

Comment: Must be a VS Issue then. Tried the usual turn it off and back on again? I take it the screen shot is from the Branches Page and that is a remote branch? Does this happen for all branches/users/etc, or just this one?

Comment: Restarted VS and tried with another branch.  I'm try to create the PR from the remote branch (after it has been published/pushed). The PR menu item is still disabled.  I did upgrade to Git version 2.7.0.windows.1.  Is it possible that could be causing this behavior?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, I can't imagine it using and local Git stuff for that.

Comment: What TFS update?  That REST endpoint is relatively new (update 1?)

Comment: Looks like the server is running TFS 2015 update 1 (version 14.0.24712.0).

Answer (score -9, accepted):

It all works fine with my VS 2015 Update1 and TFS2015 update1. Please try to delete your local repository and reconfigure it.

If it still doesn't work, reinstall the VS.

Comment: I recreated the repo but I also added the server to the VS connections/server list.  It wasn't there before.  Now it is working.

Comment: Have a look onto the post - deleting everything is not the best anwser. Your changes will get lost if your master only accepts merges by pull requests

Comment: @KeithHill The answer below should be marked as the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657064/200824

Answer (score 48):

In my case my local git repository was not "associated" with TFS.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0a0a3f7-d8fc-4e21-aff9-9702584909fe/problem-associating-work-items-with-tfs-git-repository?forum=tfsworkitemtracking) helped me discover the solution.

In Team Explorer go to "Manage Connections" -> "Connect to Team Project" which will open this window.  From here check the team project that the git repository should be associated with.

[image]

After doing so the team project should now show up in the Team Explorer.  Right click "Connect" on the newly added team project.

[image]

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Reinstall _(fill-in-the-blank)_ should never be an answer.

Comment: I absolutely, 100% agree that this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Good answer. In my case, I had not pushed the branch yet. Doh! FYI if someone else comes here and is still wondering why the "create pull request" menu item is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (coming from TFVC), it was because you cannot make pull requests from master to master. Pull requests are for individual branch development only.